# как добавить пагинацию в wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, пагинация

```
<?php $populargb = new WP_Query('showposts=5' );
    while ( $populargb->have_posts() ) {
        $populargb->the_post(); ?>
    <li>

    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">

        <div class="blog__list__img">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="blog__list__content">
            <h2 class="blog__list__content__h2"><?php the_title() ?></h2>
            <p class="blog__list__content__description"><?= get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            <span class="blog__list__content__date"><?php the_time("j F Y") ?></span>
        </div>

    </a>
    </li>
    <?php } ?>
```

Добрый день. У меня вот такой код. И я пытался сделать пагинацию, но у меня он не выводил ее. Вообще даже цифры страниц. Подскажите как добавить пагинацию ?

Comment: А что в этом коде отвечает за пагинацию? Она просто так не выводится сама по себе!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите примерно [вот это](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_posts_link#Usage_when_querying_the_loop_with_WP_Query)

```
<?php
// set the "paged" parameter (use 'page' if the query is on a static front page)
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// the query
$the_query = new WP_Query( 'cat=1&paged=' . $paged ); 
?>

<?php if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

<?php
// the loop
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); 
?>
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php

// next_posts_link() usage with max_num_pages
next_posts_link( 'Older Entries', $the_query->max_num_pages );
previous_posts_link( 'Newer Entries' );
?>

<?php 
// clean up after the query and pagination
wp_reset_postdata(); 
?>

<?php else:  ?>
<p><?php _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Ой, с телефона как-то не так, поправлю с пк

Comment: Поправил уже...

Comment: Спасибо, с телефона реально неудобно код вставлять